# Execute code when lightbox finishes loading

Tags: jquery, lightbox, onload

because I don't want to directly alter the lightbox code, I need to execute some JQuery code only when the lightbox loads entirely.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: which lightbox library are you using? Normally they all provide callbacks for when the modal window is closed, have a look at it's API.

Comment: I am using the Drupal lightbox module

Comment: Can you post a link to it? Don't know about Drupal, but as I told you, all javascript lightbox librarires I know have a callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Francisco. Our short interaction pointed me in the direction of call backs but I soon found a rich resource to further investigate.

Although I did not give the full description of my problem, I was attempting to theme the lightbox output. So my logic was perhaps I could use JQuery to remove unwanted HTML elements, leaving the LightBox as bare as possible.

To that end, I found my solution at http://drupal.org/node/252260#comment-975361

I do hope that helps others in a similar situation.